# Running ruby debug in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake, ruby-debug

I'm trying to get Ruby debugger running in one of my specs:

```
describe User do
  it "should be valid" do
    debugger
    User.new.should be_valid
  end
end
```

When I run rspec though, I get:

```
debugger statement ignored, use -d or --debug option to enable debugging
```

I've tried the following:

```
rake spec --debug
rake spec --debug  --trace
rake spec:models --debug
bundle exec rspec --debug
bundle exec rspec --debug spec/models/
bundle exec rspec --d spec/models/
bundle exec "rspec --debug" spec/models/
bundle exec rspec --debugger spec/models/
bundle exec --debugger rspec spec/models/
bundle --debugger exec rspec spec/models/
bundle --debugger exec rspec spec/models/
bundle exec --debugger rspec spec/models/
bundle exec rspec --debugger spec/models/
```

Any ideas on how to exec rspec in the right way?  I'm on Rails 3.0.5, Ruby 1.9.2, RSpec 2.5.1, ruby-debug19.

Thanks,
Justin.

Comment: I've ended up using Pry, far easier/better.  After inserting into Gemfile and installing, throw "binding.pry" anywhere in your spec, execute, and you're rolling.  See the screen cast for details.

Comment: Pry's a great object explorer, but (even with pry-nav) it just doesn't have the debugger features that the debugger gem has. I wish it did, but I've gone back to debugger.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You will get what you want by including `require 'ruby-debug'` at the top of your spec:

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'ruby-debug'

describe User do
  it "should be valid" do
    debugger
    User.new.should be_valid
  end
end
```

You would then run `rake spec` or `rspec` as normal

**NOTE:** I now prefer Ruby 2.0+ and pry. It is pretty much the same process:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'pry-debugger'

describe User do
  it "should be valid" do
    binding.pry
    expect(User.new).to be_valid
  end
end
```

Also, I generally put requires like this in my spec_helper file, so that pry-debugger is available to all of my specs.

Comment: A note here: my solution works for adding ruby debugging to one particular spec file, the solution by zetetic enables debugging for the entire project.

Comment: The solution doesn't work for me. I get: **cannot load such file -- ruby-debug (LoadError)**

Comment: Re: the above. Needed to uncomment the Gemfile line with the ruby-debug19 gem.  (Put it into :test, :development groups actually.) Works now.

Comment: Depends on the GEM You use for debugging. I use `"pry-rails"` and `"pry-byebug"` so I would `require 'pry-rails'`. Also in the Gemfile they need to be included in the `test environment`

Answer (score 22):

### For Ruby >= 1.9.2

You should install the **[debugger](http://github.com/cldwalker/debugger)** gem **instead of** ruby-debug19. It you use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/), you just put this in your Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem "debugger"
end
```

After that you can just put

#### rspec < 3.0

```
--debug
```

#### rspec >= 3.0

```
-rdebugger
```

in your `.rspec` file

Then you can just run

```
bundle exec rake spec
```

without any additional arguments. There is **no need to modify your source code** either (not even your test source code)

Comment: +1 and thanks for pointing that out. There is no code modification to *enable* the debugger, but you do have to modify your test code to *invoke* the debugger, exactly as shown at the top of the original question (add a `debugger` statement). Also, if you run your test with spork, the rdb prompt will appear in the spork console, which doesn't echo what you type in. Seems easiest to run without spork.

Comment: and if you use byebug, then it becomes -rbyebug

Answer (score 20):

For ruby 2.0 I use byebug: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug

```
gem 'byebug'
```

Code:

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'byebug'

describe User do
  it "should be valid" do
    byebug
    User.new.should be_valid
  end
end
```

Comment: For some reason, this solution doesn't work. Passes over the test

Comment: @Trip that's interesting, maybe instead of `byebug` try adding `debugger`?

Answer (score 9):

The best way I have found to debug in rSpec is by adding the following to your 'spec_helper.rb' file

```
def logger
  Rails.logger
end
```

You can then access all the logger methods within your rSpec files and incorporate such things as tagged logging. This of course is for Rails 3 and up. If you have anything prior to Rails 3 then add this instead:

```
def logger
  RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER
end
```

Once you have your logging statements in place you can enter

```
tail -f log/test.log
```

in your terminal shell in order to watch your logging statements while the tests are run.

Of course in your actual rspec test you would enter something such as

```
logger.debug "#{1.class}"  # => Fixnum
```

If you want to filter your debug statements from the rest of your test log simply prepend a random string on to your debug statement and pipe the output of the tail command to grep.

Example:

```
logger.debug "random_string #{1.class}"   # => Fixnum

tail -f log/test.log | grep random_string
```

#### Update

I've changed my opinion on this. You should install pry, pry-doc, and pry-debug, pry-debugger, and pry-rails. Then use binding.pry in your code to open an interactive debugger console that rules the world!

Comment: Huge +1, this is a really great tip

Comment: This did not answer the question.

Comment: phatmann, this is the most correct way in Rails 3 to allow for logging in rspec tests. Once you have added the method to your spec_helper.rb file you can then log debug statements by using 

`logger.debug "#{1.class}"`

If you want you can prepend a random string to your debug statement and pipe the output of the tail command to grep in order to filter your debugging statements.

Comment: Downvoting. The OP was asking about debugger breakpoints, not logging (which isn't the greatest idea in specs anyway).

Comment: Downvoting, for same reason as @MarnenLaibow-Koser.  May be useful info, but doesn't answer the OP's actual question.

Answer (score 4):

The best and cleanest option is to use `--require` in your `.rspec` file.  What you put depends on which gem you use for debugging.

```
--color
--require pry
--require rails_helper
```

These correspond to command line options (-d or --debug is now deprecated).

Feel free to use `debugger`, `ruby-debug` or `pry` (pry-rails in your Gemfile).

For your Gemfile:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'pry-rails'
end
```

Putting `require 'ruby-debug'` etc. at the top of your spec is simply more tightly coupled -- especially since here the top voted comment suggests putting it individually in ALL your files. With the new `.rspec` file you shouldn't need to put `require 'spec_helper'` or `require 'rails_helper'` at the top of your files anymore.

They make more sense as implicit command line arguments.