# Rails 3.2.0 rspec debugger not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've just upgraded to ruby 1.9.3-p0 and rails 3.2.0. I'm now trying to debug an error in one of my tests using

```
rspec spec -d
```

But I get this error:

```
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:422:in `rescue in debug=':  (RuntimeError)
**************************************************
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so: undefined symbol: ruby_threadptr_data_type - /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so

If you have it installed as a ruby gem, then you need to either require
'rubygems' or configure the RUBYOPT environment variable with the value
'rubygems'.

/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `require'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `require'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:408:in `require'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:408:in `debug='
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:19:in `block in configure'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:18:in `each'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:18:in `configure'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
/home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
**************************************************
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:407:in `debug='
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:19:in `block in configure'
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:18:in `each'
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:18:in `configure'
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3.2/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stick this in your Gemfile:

```
# one-liner to install these properly: bash < <(curl -L https://raw.github.com/gist/1333785)
gem 'linecache19', '0.5.13'
gem 'ruby-debug-base19', '0.11.26'
```

You'll need to run that one-liner in order for bundler to pick up the proper gems.

EDIT: I forgot to link to the posts I used to get debugging working:

- [ruby-debug with Ruby 1.9.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087610/ruby-debug-with-ruby-1-9-3)
- [ruby-debug19 on ruby-1.9.3-preview1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054948/ruby-debug19-on-ruby-1-9-3-preview1)

Answer (score 10):

Install the new debugger gem that works with Ruby 1.9.3 and 1.9.2:

```
https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger
```

Comment: Looks like the [debugger gem](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) is specifically designed to handle Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3. It's a fork of ruby-debug19 ([Reason for Fork](http://rubydoc.info/gems/debugger/1.2.0/file/README.md#Reason_for_Fork)). See easy installation instructions in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12294770/550712).

Comment: For those using Debugger and still getting errors, see this [Github issue thread](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/12).  Some people had to manually install debugger dependencies.  That thread wasn't exactly what I needed, but something in it led me to the solution I needed, which was to reinstall my rvm, rubies and gcc dependencies after migrating to a new system...

Answer (score 2):

I guess I can't comment on other answers yet, but I found many of these instructions don't mention you'll still need to include the

`gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'`

line in your Gemfile, *in addition* to the instructions siannopollo provides. Without this, I get a 'cannot load such file -- ruby-debug' error (OSX, rvm, 1.9.3-p125).

FWIW, the gist is hardcoded to 1.9.3-p0, so if you're on 1.9.3-p125, you might need to edit it (also, generally a bad idea to execute a gist you haven't read).

Answer (score 2):

For me, all it took was:

```
gem 'debugger'
```

in the `Gemfile`

Answer (score 1):

Had to upgrade the following

```
bundle update ruby-debug-base19
```