# breakpoints in methods during rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rspec, breakpoints

I'd like to start debugger in methods during rspec test. I know, I can do it in the spec ([like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446594/running-ruby-debug-in-rspec)), I have `--debug` in my `.rspec` file.

I'd like to put `debugger` in a methods that is under tests:

```
it "should be OK" do
    User.ok? should be_true
end

class User
    def ok?
        do_something
        debugger      #here is my breakpoint
        do_something
    end
end
```

When I do something similar to that example and run rspec (using `rake spec` or `guard` or `rspec`) the breakpoind doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your debugger gem under the :test group in your gemfile.

```
gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```