# how do i print the description of every rspec to the Rails.logger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I want to show each example's description in the Rails log during debugging. I can't quite figure out how this is done. I've looked at using RSpec.configure doing something like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do |example|
    Rails.logger.debug example.description
  end
end
```

but that just gives a NoMethodError as it can't find description at that point. I thought it might work like #around does, but I guess not.

Comment: This should help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10199575/429758

Comment: @PrakashMurthy actually, not at all. I know how to use the Rails logger, that's not the issue. What I want is to have each test's description written to the Rails log when it is run. I *don't* particularly want to have to edit every spec file to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close, the following will output your test descriptions as they're run:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.before(:each) do
     Rails.logger.debug self.class.description         
   end
end
```

Source: http://benmabey.com/2008/07/04/global-setup-in-rspec-or-how-to-add-logging-for-specs.html